# How do I chain action and interpret them together with Scalaz?

Tags: scala, scalaz, free-monad

I am trying to learn how to use FreeMonads to implement interpreters for my services.

Suppose I have

```
sealed trait ServiceAction[T] extends Product with Serializable
case class ConsumeCommand(cmd: AccruePoints) extends ServiceAction[AccruePointModel]
case class CreateEvent(evt: PointsAccruedEvent) extends ServiceAction[PointsAccruedEvent]

sealed trait LogAction[T] extends Product with Serializable
case class Info(msg: String) extends LogAction[Unit]
case class Error(msg: String) extends LogAction[Unit]
```

and a Monad of the action

```
type LogActionF[A] = Free[LogAction, A]
type ServiceActionF[A] = Free[ServiceAction, A]
```

Next, I define my service like this:

```
trait PointAccrualService {
    def consume(cmd: AccruePoints): ServiceActionF[AccruePointModel] = Free.liftF(ConsumeCommand(cmd))
    def emit(evt: PointsAccruedEvent) : ServiceActionF[PointsAccruedEvent] = Free.liftF(CreateEvent(evt))
}
```

and

```
trait LogService {
  def info(msg: String) : LogActionF[Unit] = Free.liftF(Info(msg))
  def error(msg: String) : LogActionF[Unit] = Free.liftF(Error(msg))
}
```

with an object of each

```
object LogService extends LogService
object PointAccrualService extends PointAccrualService
```

My `LogServiceInterpreter` is like this:

```
case class LogServiceConsoleInterpreter() extends LogServiceInterpreter {
  def apply[A](action: LogActionF[A]): Task[A] = action.foldMap(handler)             

    protected def handler = new (LogAction ~> Task) {
    override def apply[A](fa: LogAction[A]) = fa match {
      case Info(m) =>
        now(info(m))
      case Error(m) =>
        now(error(m))
    }
  }

  def info(msg: String): Unit = {
    println(s"INFO: $msg")
  }

  def error(msg: String): Unit = {
    println(s"ERROR: $msg")
  }
}
```

Similarly, my `PointAccuralServiceInterpreter` is like this:

```
case class PointAccuralServiceInterpreter() {
  def apply[A] (action: ServiceActionF[A]) : Task[A] = action.foldMap(handler)
  protected def handler = new (ServiceAction ~> Task) {
    override def apply[A](fa: ServiceAction[A]): Task[A] = fa match {
      case ConsumeCommand(cmd) => {
        println("Service ConsumeCommand:" + cmd)
        now(cmd)
      }
      case CreateEvent(evt) => {
        println("Service CreateEvent:" + evt)
        now(evt)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My logic is straightforward, I want to log, and consume my command and then create an event, sort of like an event sourcing:

```
val ret = for {
  _ <- logService.info("Command: " + cmd)
  model <- service.consume(cmd)
  _ <- logService.info("Model: " + model)
  evt <- service.emit(model.toEvent("200", "Event Sent"))
  _ <- logService.info("Event:" + evt)
} yield evt
```

This code doesn't even compile actually.

What should I do from here? I think I am supposed to use Coproduct to chain them and execute this piece of logic by feeding my interpreter.

I found something here 
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/scalaz/sHxFsFpE86c

or it's said I can use Shapeless to do so
[Folding a list of different types using Shapeless in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33971404/folding-a-list-of-different-types-using-shapeless-in-scala)

They are all too complicated. All I want is, after I define my logic, how do I execute it?

Hope I put enough details here for an answer. I really want to learn this. Thanks

Comment: Your question is not clear at all.

Comment: sorry, let me add more code. I rushed out for a lunch with other people. I should have put more in the body

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I slightly modified your code to create a self-contained running example. I also added a possible answer to your question, how to execute your program, following [Rúnar Bjarnason's ideas](http://functionaltalks.org/2014/11/23/runar-oli-bjarnason-free-monad/), using Scalaz 7.2. (I did not find the `or` operator for the natural transformations in Scalaz, so I added it here.)

I also added a few stubs to give your actions something to fiddle with and simplified your services to the handlers inside (since I had to create a new service for both languages combined). Furthermore I changed your `Task.now{...}` to `Task{...}` to create an asynchronous Task, which is executed on the last line of code.

Here is the full code:

```scala
import scala.language.{higherKinds, implicitConversions}

import scalaz._
import scalaz.concurrent.Task

/* Stubs */

case class AccruePoints()
case class AccruePointModel(cmd: AccruePoints) {
  def toEvent(code: String, description: String): PointsAccruedEvent = PointsAccruedEvent(code, description)
}
case class PointsAccruedEvent(code: String, description: String)

/* Actions */

sealed trait ServiceAction[T] extends Product with Serializable

case class ConsumeCommand(cmd: AccruePoints) extends ServiceAction[AccruePointModel]
case class CreateEvent(evt: PointsAccruedEvent) extends ServiceAction[PointsAccruedEvent]

sealed trait LogAction[T] extends Product with Serializable

case class Info(msg: String) extends LogAction[Unit]
case class Error(msg: String) extends LogAction[Unit]

/* Handlers */

object PointAccuralServiceHandler extends (ServiceAction ~> Task) {
  override def apply[A](fa: ServiceAction[A]): Task[A] = fa match {
    case ConsumeCommand(cmd) => {
      println("Service ConsumeCommand:" + cmd)
      Task(consume(cmd))
    }
    case CreateEvent(evt) => {
      println("Service CreateEvent:" + evt)
      Task(evt)
    }
  }

  def consume(cmd: AccruePoints): AccruePointModel =
    AccruePointModel(cmd)
}

case object LogServiceConsoleHandler extends (LogAction ~> Task) {
  override def apply[A](fa: LogAction[A]): Task[A] = fa match {
    case Info(m) =>
      Task(info(m))
    case Error(m) =>
      Task(error(m))
  }

  def info(msg: String): Unit = {
    println(s"INFO: $msg")
  }

  def error(msg: String): Unit = {
    println(s"ERROR: $msg")
  }
}

/* Execution */

class Service[F[_]](implicit I1: Inject[ServiceAction, F], I2: Inject[LogAction, F]) {
  def consume(cmd: AccruePoints): Free[F, AccruePointModel] = Free.liftF(I1(ConsumeCommand(cmd)))

  def emit(evt: PointsAccruedEvent): Free[F, PointsAccruedEvent] = Free.liftF(I1(CreateEvent(evt)))

  def info(msg: String): Free[F, Unit] = Free.liftF(I2(Info(msg)))

  def error(msg: String): Free[F, Unit] = Free.liftF(I2(Error(msg)))
}

object Service {
  implicit def instance[F[_]](implicit I1: Inject[ServiceAction, F], I2: Inject[LogAction, F]) = new Service[F]
}

def prg[F[_]](implicit service: Service[F]) = {
  val cmd = AccruePoints()
  for {
    _ <- service.info("Command: " + cmd)
    model <- service.consume(cmd)
    _ <- service.info("Model: " + model)
    evt <- service.emit(model.toEvent("200", "Event Sent"))
    _ <- service.info("Event:" + evt)
  } yield evt
}

type App[A] = Coproduct[ServiceAction, LogAction, A]

def or[F[_], G[_], H[_]](f: F ~> H, g: G ~> H) =
  new (({type t[x] = Coproduct[F, G, x]})#t ~> H) {
    override def apply[A](c: Coproduct[F, G, A]): H[A] = c.run match {
      case -\/(fa) => f(fa)
      case \/-(ga) => g(ga)
    }
  }

val app = prg[App]

val ret = app.foldMap(or(PointAccuralServiceHandler, LogServiceConsoleHandler))
ret.unsafePerformSync
```